# Отказоустойчивость серверов

Tags: mysql, сервер, nginx, redis

Суть проблемы в том, что если упадет сервер с приложением, то запросы пойдут на другой, и такая же проблема с серверами mysql и redis.

1. Сервер:
   Чтобы гарантировать отказоустойчивость сервера, достаточно купить 2 сервера и зарегистрировать их на один домен ?
2. БД(Mysql):
   Сделать 2 мастера, чтобы они ссылались друг на друга и в случае если один упадет, то все запросы перейдут на другой ? И как сделать чтобы приложение само знало на какой сервер mysql/redis посылать запросы, такой же трюк как с сервером сделать  ?

Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему ?

Схема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае, надо реализовать балансировщик нагрузки на базе NGINX (модуль ngx_http_upstream_module). Он будет принимать запросы для указанного домена и перенаправлять их на свободный или менее загруженный бакенд (сервер приложений). Для баз данных надо настроить Master и Slave сервер и сделать между ними репликацию.

Answer (score 0):

Для обеспечения отказоустойчивости можно также создать linux кластер на основе pacemaker из двух или больше нод (серверов), создать сервисный IP с именем, который будет подниматься на одном из узлов кластера. Приложения подключать к базам по этому сервисному имени.
Все узлы должны располагаться в идеале в разных ЦОД, иначе отказоустойчивости не будет.